# Select records and group each time column changes

Tags: mysql

I have this (MySQL) database, sorted by increasing timestamp:

```
Timestamp     RateSingle    RateDouble    RoomId
2022-01-01     100            150           1     
2022-01-02     100            150           1     
2022-01-03     150            200           1
2022-01-04     150            200           1
2022-01-05     200            250           1      
2022-01-06     200            250           1      
2011-01-07     300            350           1
```

What I am trying to do is group the Timestamp and select rates each time RateSingle changes.

Expected result

```
      Timestamp          RateSingle    RateDouble    
2022-01-01 - 2022-01-02    100            150               
2022-01-03 - 2022-01-04    150            200           
2022-01-05 - 2022-01-06    200            250                
2011-01-07                 300            350
```

My query so far works only partly:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `room_rates` AS a
WHERE a.RateSingle <>
      ( SELECT b.RateSingle
        FROM `room_rates` AS b
        WHERE a.RoomId= b.RoomId
          AND a.Timestamp> b.Timestamp
        ORDER BY b.Timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(RateSingle) %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp = paste(Timestamp, lead(Timestamp), sep = " - ")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  Timestamp               RateSingle RateDouble RoomId
  <chr>                        <int>      <int>  <int>
1 2022-01-01 - 2022-01-02        100        150      1
2 2022-01-03 - 2022-01-04        150        200      1
3 2022-01-05 - 2022-01-06        200        250      1
4 2011-01-07 - NA                300        350      1
```

Comment: thank you, your solution is achieving the desired output as you have shown but I would like to have it using only mysql without any third party libraries.

Comment: @HamzaZahir  when you add `r` tag in the post, it can create some confusion for users whether you require `r` solution or `mysql`.  It is better to use only the `mysql` tag.  Thanks